# Problem with Tex Live Utility

Tags: texlive, mactex, texlive-2016

I recently upgraded to MacTeX 2016 but when I launch TeX Live Utility I have this message:

> your tex live version is 0 but your default repository url appears to
>   be for tex live 2016. You need to manually upgrade to a newer version
>   of TexLive, as there will be no further upgrades to your version.

I tried to uninstall all versions of MacTeX and reinstall only the 2016 package but it keeps saying that. I am on version 1.24 of TLU.
Maybe it doesn't point to the correct directory but I don't know what is the correct path.

Comment: I got this problem but solved it by going to the menu item Configure>Manage Repositories, choose one, then Configure>Set as Home Repository, then exit Texlive and launched it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open TeX Live Utility's Preferences window and ensure that the path is set correctly for MacTeX. Use the button to choose `/Library/TeX/texbin` or drop that folder on the path bar. [image: Screenshot of Preferences]

Answer (score 1):

You probably set `TeX programs: in 'TeX Live Utility->Preferences manually at some point. Please go to <http://www.tug.org/mactex/elcapitan.html> and look at section 6 of the linked`Updating For El Capitan' document.